# ASP.NET MVC - Auto-redirect to external site in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that redirects to another view with a simple message after submitting a form. Here (in the view with a simple success message) I would like to be able to redirect automatically after 5 seconds to an external website. This works fine:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://external.site">
```

The problem is that the url I need to redirect to is dynamic and I have it stored in the Model but this is not working (this reload itself or it does nothing, no error in Chrome console):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=@Model.SuccessfulRedirectUrl">
```

I also tried some Javascript but this is not working due to an error similar to this in the Chrome console

**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive ...**

and this is the code:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var redirectUrl = @Model.SuccessfulRedirectUrl;
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = redirectUrl;
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is the controller that take care of the form submit

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyController(MyControllerInputModel myControllerInputModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Here there are only DB Querys to get data I need ...

            // redirectUrl is from DB
            return RedirectToAction("RedirectController", new RedirectModel(redirectUrl));
        }
        
        return View(new AnotherView()));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

The controller of the simple message (RedirectController) just return a new View passing the redirect url specified

Can someone tell me if it is possible to do what I want? As an alternative solution, I can think only to put a button in the page to let the user redirect on click but it's not the same at all

Comment: The JS variant needs quotes: `var redirectUrl = "@Model.SuccessfulRedirectUrl";`. And make sure to do 'view source' on the webpage to verify that the generated script is syntactically correct.

Comment: In sources tab shows "URL=" (it's empty) but from debugging session I can tell the value it's there and in a correct form (I saved the url as string in the ViewModel)

Comment: Show the MVC Controller code please that assigns the URL to the `(View)Model.SuccessfulRedirectUrl` property. Or is it put in `ViewBag` (big difference)? Be as complete as you can.

Comment: In other words, you need to provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a mistake in the Controllers. I am fairly new to this and I was passing the wrong parameter when using RedirectToAction.

This was the old (and wrong) RedirectToAction:

`return RedirectToAction("RedirectController", new RedirectModel(redirectUrl));`

This is the modified (and working) RedirectToAction:

`return RedirectToAction("RedirectController", new { redirectUrl = user.RedirectUrl });`

After this edit, this solution is working correctly:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=@Model.SuccessfulRedirectUrl">`